# How to compare a single stored procedure across 100s of databases? T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I need a way to compare a stored procedure across multiple (hundreds and hundreds) of databases. Not just compare two at a time. It looks like ApexSQL only does two at a time (unless I am mistaken). This won't work because it will take forever. I need to group by the stored procedure so I can identify which groups I can make certain changes to.

I tried the following code solution:

```
select 
    'select OBJECT_NAME(object_id), OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) from ' + 
    name + '.sys.procedures where name like ''sp_someProcedure%'' union'  
from 
    master.sys.databases
```

I then tried to throw the scripts that outputted into a sub select where I do a group by the stored procedure. This doesn't work because for some reason you can't union between multiple databases for sys stuff (unless I am mistaken). Each select statement stays in the context of what you are using.  So use databaseOne stays in databaseOne even though the following select statement is select blah blah blah from databaseTwo.

Any thoughts?

Comment: To me that sounds like it should work, but what if you just insert into a temp table the results from each of the databases?

Comment: OBJECT_NAME and OBJECT_DEFINITION both are using the current database. You can get the definition from sql_modules and sys.procedures has the name anyway.

Comment: Do you expect a lot of them to be the same? If so, a `CHECKSUM()` of the definition will tell you which ones are different. But the approach that you have should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, let's start off topic with a useful article: [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). Don't start your SP's name with `sp_`, it's reserved by Microsoft for system stored procedures. The article discusses further as to why it's a bad idea; but simply put, your SP could just (suddenly) stop working one day, and also it can have a performance hit.

Now, more on topic. You could instead use the **undocumented** sp `sp_msforeachdb`. This results in something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #Procs (ObjectName sysname, ObjectDefination nvarchar(MAX));

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);
SET @SQL = N'SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id)' + NCHAR(10) +
           N'FROM [?].sys.procedures' + NCHAR(10) + 
           N'WHERE [name] LIKE ''sp_someProcedure%'';';

INSERT INTO #Procs
EXEC sp_msforeachdb @SQL;

SELECT *
FROM #Procs;

DROP TABLE #Procs;
```